# Burger Menu open and close animation is choppy on Safari and mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, css-animations

Here is a link https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MpxWVhlp360 showing a video of the problem. This only happens on mobile browsers and Safari. I have tried to enable hardware rendering by using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` But unfortunately it couln't fix the problem.

Here is the CSS/SCSS code

```
@import "../../styles/colors.scss";

.burger {
  all: unset;
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 8;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid $light-blue;
  row-gap: 4px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left center;
  }
}

.menu {
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 326px;
  max-width: 326px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: $dark-background;
  padding: 77px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 30px;
  right: -326px;
  top: 0;
  .link {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.37;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
    &:hover {
      color: $light-blue;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}

.open {
  row-gap: 5.07px;

  span:nth-child(1) {
    animation: open1 500ms linear forwards;
  }
  span:nth-child(2) {
    animation: open2 500ms linear forwards;
  }
  span:nth-child(3) {
    animation: open3 500ms linear forwards;
  }
}

.close {
  span {
    row-gap: 4px;
  }
  span:nth-child(1) {
    animation: close1 500ms linear forwards;
  }
  span:nth-child(2) {
    animation: close2 500ms linear forwards;
  }
  span:nth-child(3) {
    animation: close3 500ms linear forwards;
  }
}

.slide {
  animation: slide 500ms linear forwards;
}

.slide_back {
  animation: slide-back 500ms linear forwards;
}

@keyframes open1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(2.93px) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: $light-blue;
  }
}

@keyframes open2 {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes open3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(2.93px) rotate(315deg);
    background-color: $light-blue;
  }
}

@keyframes close1 {
  from {
    transform: translateX(2.93px) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: $light-blue;
  }

  to {
    transform: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

@keyframes close2 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes close3 {
  from {
    transform: translateX(2.93px) rotate(315deg);
    background-color: $light-blue;
  }

  to {
    transform: none;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  to {
    right: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-back {
  from {
    right: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: -326px;
  }
}
```

Here is the react jsx/html to go with the css:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DownloadButton from "../download-button/DownloadButton";
import styles from "./burger-menu-styles.module.scss";
import classNames from "classnames";

export default function BurgerMenu() {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [burgerMenuActive, setBurgerMenuActive] = useState(false);
  const activateBurgerMenu = () => {
    if (!isMounted) {
      setIsMounted(true);
      setBurgerMenuActive(!burgerMenuActive);
    } else setBurgerMenuActive(!burgerMenuActive);
  };
  const burgerClasses = classNames({
    [styles.burger]: true,
    [styles.open]: burgerMenuActive,
    [styles.close]: !burgerMenuActive && isMounted,
  });

  const menuClasses = classNames({
    [styles.menu]: true,
    [styles.slide]: burgerMenuActive,
    [styles.slide_back]: !burgerMenuActive && isMounted,
  });
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className={menuClasses}>
        <a href="#about" onClick={activateBurgerMenu} className={styles.link}>
          About
        </a>
        <a
          href="#services"
          onClick={activateBurgerMenu}
          className={styles.link}
        >
          Experience
        </a>
        <a href="#work" onClick={activateBurgerMenu} className={styles.link}>
          Work
        </a>
        <a href="#contact" onClick={activateBurgerMenu} className={styles.link}>
          Contact Me
        </a>
        <DownloadButton href="/assets/batetambe_tanyi.pdf">
          Resume
        </DownloadButton>
      </div>
      <button className={burgerClasses} onClick={activateBurgerMenu}>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```